# Passing object from parent to child returning object name as string angular

Tags: javascript, angular, data-sharing

When ever I try to pass object from parent to child I get variable name as string.

[image: editData]

note this edit data should return exactly as the object above it in the pic.

I am using a `ViewChild`in child component to get data from parent.

`message="editData"`

```
<app-add-user-form message="editData" (showUserForm)="hideUserForm($event)" (submitUsersData)="pushToArray($event)"></app-add-user-form>
```

[stack bliz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yu82sm)

Comment: use `[message]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not binding to the property. Use square bracket notation to bind the property to your model.

```
[message]="editData"
```

Comment: Thank @kurt I am debugging since 2 hours and here it is. Thank you very much.